# How to replace a suffix of a string?

Tags: python, string

I know how to make string replacements in Python but I need a way to replace only if the sequence is located at the end of the word.

For example:

Rule: `at` → `ate`

So `cat` is changed to `cate`.

But `attorney` stays unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regex can do that with ease:

```
import re

regx = re.compile('at\\b')

ch = 'the fat cat was impressed by all the rats gathering at one corner of the great room'

print ch
print regx.sub('ATU',ch)
```

Result:

```
the fat cat was impressed by all the rats gathering at one corner of the great room
the fATU cATU was impressed by all the rats gathering ATU one corner of the greATU room
```

With regexes, we can perform very complicated tasks.

For example, replacing several kinds of strings with a particular replacement for each, thanks to the use of a callback function (here named `repl`, that receives catched MatchObjects)

```
import re

regx = re.compile('(at\\b)|([^ ]r(?! ))')

def repl(mat, dic = {1:'ATU',2:'XIXI'}):
    return dic[mat.lastindex]

ch = 'the fat cat was impressed by all the rats gathering at one corner of the great room'

print ch
print regx.sub(repl,ch)
```

Result:

```
the fat cat was impressed by all the rats gathering at one corner of the great room
the fATU cATU was imXIXIessed by all the rats gathXIXIing ATU one cXIXIner of the XIXIeATU room
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no special method to do this, but it's quite simple anyways:

```
w = 'at'
repl = 'ate'
s = 'cat'

if s.endswith(w):
    # if s ends with w, take only the part before w and add the replacement
    s = s[:-len(w)] + repl
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions with the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module and the following code:

```
re.sub(re.escape(suffix)+"$", replacement, word)
```

If you need to do this for text longer than a single word

```
re.sub(re.escape(suffix)+r"\b", replacement, word)
```

because `\b` is a word boundary, so a suffix followed by a word boundary is at the end of any word in the text

Comment: Don't forget to `re.escape(suffix)`.

Comment: This only works if the word is at the end of the line/string though.