# Python, if the end of a RANDOM string in a list is xy, how do I replace it with yx?

Tags: python

For example this is my random list

```
list = ["asdxy", "abcyx", "asd"]
```

I want it to be this

```
list = ["asdyx", "abcyx", "asd"]
```

Comment: I really don't think there's simple method better than try the items one by one.

Comment: Relevant: [string suffix replacement in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6363286/6045800)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the method [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) to check for the suffix of a string object.
In your case I would do the transformation of the list as:

```
my_list = ["asdxy", "abcyx", "asd"]
my_modified_list = [word[:-2] + "yx" if word.endswith("xy") else word for word in my_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to find the end of every word and check if it is `'xy'` and replace it:

```
list_t = ["asdxy", "abcyx", "asd"]

my_list = [s[:-2] + "yx" if s[-2:] == "xy" else s for s in list_t ]

print(my_list)  # prints ["asdyx", "abcyx", "asd"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a hack for fun:

```
lst = eval(str(lst).replace("xy'", "yx'"))
```

Two more ways:

```
import re
lst = [re.sub('xy$', 'yx', s) for s in lst]
```

```
lst = [s[:-2] + s[-2:].replace('xy', 'yx') for s in lst]
```

Comment: To make it an actual usable/safe hack, use `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @Tomerikoo As far as I understand, they have a list of strings. Can you show one where this isn't usable/safe?

Comment: I can't think of one but it could be possible... Why not use a safe option when there is one?

Comment: @Tomerikoo `ast.literal_eval` isn't safe, either. Time to update your mental model about it :-). And I'm not using `eval` on an arbitrary string but on one produced by `str` (and then just modified in a way that doesn't introduce danger).

Answer (score 0):

bringing a howitzer to a knife fight...

```
import re
my_list = ["asdxy", "abcyx", "asd"]
new_list  = []
for entry in my_list:
    a_match=re.match("^(.*)xy$",entry)
    if a_match:
        new_list.append(a_match.group(1)+"yx")
    else:
        new_list.append(entry)
```

Comment: And then using the howitzer wearing a blindfold :-P

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using `map`:

```
lst = ["asdxy", "abcyx", "asd"]
lst = [*map(lambda i:(i[:-2]+'yx',i)[i[-2:]!='xy'],lst)]
```

Or:

```
lst = ["asdxy", "abcyx", "asd"]
lst = [(i[:-2]+'yx',i)[i[-2:]!='xy'] for i in lst]
```